# How do I use Play Store "app signing" keys to update my app when I have forgotten my keystore password?

Tags: android-studio, google-play, keystore, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I forgot my Android Studio keystore password which I used to build my app first release, although I still have the .jks and .pepk files saved on my computer. Now, unfortunately I want to update the app on PlayStore. Is it possible to recover the keystore details from the .jks and .pepk files? How?

Also: When publishing the app on PlayStore I opted for Google Play "app signing", which I understood then to mean that I would still be able to upload updates to my app even if I lose/forget my keystore details. So, now that I have forgotten my keys, how do I update my app with new version using the Play store upload keys generated during app signing?

I can't update the app release using new .aab file with different keystore details.

Please I need someone to clarify me on how to make use of app signing upload keys to update my app release bundle now that I have forgotten my keystore password.